# Is it possible to include .bmp figure?

Tags: plot

Do any need a special package to include .bmp figures in a document? Because it gaves me an error if I try to include them in the document.

I tried saving the figures as .jpg, but the quality is really low. Am I forced to use the .eps format to be able to include high quality figures?

Comment: You can convert from bmp to png, which doesn't change the quality. What is the image you are trying to use of? If it is a graph or some other mathematical stuff you should use vectors (eps/pdf).

Comment: I have to include both graphs and figures (like block-diagrams) and I was looking to some kind of format which fit well for both.

Comment: You should include those as vectors, and not pixel images.

Comment: Try to export directly to pdf instead of eps. You will have to convert it sooner or later to pdf, so you can use it from the start and save yourself some time and potential headegg.